# How to display values from SQL-Database in UTF-8 Format using Docker Container with MySQL, Flask, nginx?

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, utf-8

I am quite new to SQL, Flask, and overall web-developement but I wanted to learn about it so I started a little project.

The Problem appears when I try to display content from my SQL-Tables on the website. It does not display the letter ü, instead it shows Ã¼.

Texts on the website and Strings which where assigned in python are not affected by this problem.

**Setup:**

- MySQL Docker Container with database which contains preloaded Contents, loaded from an SQL-File:

```
use db;

CREATE TABLE example(
    ExampleID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ExampleText varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ExampleID)
);

INSERT INTO example(ExampleText)
VALUES("ü");
```

- Python Container using Flask Framework to display data from MySQL-Tables on the Website like this:

```
@views.route("/")
def index():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ExampleText FROM questions')
    value = cursor.fetchone()
    return render_template("index.html", displayed_text=value[0])
```

- Ngnx Container, but this should not be the problem.

At first I tried to solve the problem with the following command in my docker-compose.yaml File: `command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']`

After this I tried to change the Charset inside the SQL File from above:

```
ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

use db;

CREATE TABLE example(
    ExampleID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ExampleText varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ExampleID)
);

ALTER TABLE example CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO example(ExampleText)
VALUES("ü");
```

Both did not work.

After every change I tried, I deleted the existing containers, Images and Volumes and also cleared the build cache so there shouldn't be a problem coming from docker using the wrong cached version of anything.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ü'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` shows `'Ã¼'`. Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), see also 
[UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/)… Specify the character encoding for the HTML document:

```<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>```

Comment: `Ã¼` looks like "Mojibake" for `ü`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for likely causes.